# floating 3 divs in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I'm a noob to html programming, but basically I want to have 3 divisions that look something like this:

```
|        |        |
|    1   |    2   |
|        |        |
-------------------
|                 |
|        3        |
|                 |
```

Right now, I'm using bootstrap and I can have columns beside each other using the div classes. But that only works if I want to do columns. For example:

```
 <div class=col-lg-6>
```

Also, I can't use a fixed size, because div2 might be bigger than div1 or vice versa depending on the info that I get. Any suggestions to how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Did you want something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/zqptbjur/

This is utilizing Twitter Boostsrap CSS:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="background: gray;">
            Content1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="background: wheat;">
            Content2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background: tan;">
            Content3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I just wasnt thinking properly. I didnt realize how easy it was just to put two divisions in like the division row thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javascript, you can make those divs have fluid width like 30%, 70% and set their display property to 'inline-block', set the wrapping div's white-space property to 'nowrap'. After that, adding a br tag will drop the third div down. ..or you can just use table layout which I'd never suggest.